# In the Time Odyssey series, is there going to be a sequel to Firstborn?

Tags: arthur-c-clarke, stephen-baxter, time-odyssey

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Time_Odyssey) says that an edition of Firstborn calls it the conclusion.  After reading Firstborn, I was looking forward to the next book, where I hoped we'd see

> the humans take the fight to the Firstborn.

But I see that Arthur C. Clarke died since that book was written, so I don't know if they completed the story.  Has anyone heard if the next book is being worked on?

Comment: I have ridden the ways of Google for about an hour now, and I cant find anything else than "a sequel is not yet planned" and "Firstborn is the final book"... I hope somebody can find out more, at least I tried!

Comment: @WizardOz I'll take a 'No' as an answer. Post an answer, with links to your sources, and I'll approve.

Comment: This question was asked again [here](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/28662/did-stephen-baxter-or-arthur-c-clarkes-estate-ever-comment-on-continuing-a-ti)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple answer: No.
Only reference on the web by December 2011 is "a sequel is not yet planned".

Comment: Can you add a link to where it says that?

Comment: Sorry, I didnt bookmark the pages when I did the research in Desember. I will however try to dig it up again when I have the time.

Answer (score 1):

I can find no mention of a proposed sequel, also, I can't find evidence for the answer given above this does *not* mean it was once not there.

[Here](http://www.concatenation.org/frev/firstborn_clarke_baxter.html) we find a reviewer asking the same question (last updated 08.9.15)

> So why have I gone to the trouble of mentioning such idle speculation with you? Well since the first two books were clearly not a duology, am I convinced that Firstborn really is 'the conclusion to 'A Time Odyssey'? Nope.   Given this could there be more?   Well given that the book ends with a short one-page chapter that presents matters on a new level one cannot but help speculate that there really is more to come. It may be that Arthur had time to jot down some notes and share these with Stephen? If so expect another book. Having said that, and if this really has happened, I really do urge Stephen to take his time. The three books in this series to date do appear to have been hurriedly written and do have some unsatisfactory inconsistencies that could (should) have been ironed out. Of course I can dream... Poole, Bowman and Hal meeting Reid Malenfant. Done right that would really be something.